# Event in Datagrid inquiry

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is there a datagrid event that will know which particular datagrid cell is clicked or selected?

I want to modify the style of the selected datagrid cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific event for that, but you can use the CurrentCellChanged event .

Then use the DataGrid's CurrentColumn and SelectedIndex properties to determine which cell was clicked.